# Do an action before any subscriber callback of an Observable is called in RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-android

I have an `Observable` chain (RxJava 1) and I want to do some one-off action when the observable finishes its work (just before it emits something), but ***before any subscriber callback is called*** (I want to update some `AtomicBoolean` value, and have all subscribers see the new value).

What is my best bet to do this in a thread-safe way?

I checked `doOnTerminate`, `doOnCompleted`, `doAfterTerminate` **but it seems there are no guarantees about the order**: I put some logs, and sometimes a first subscriber callback is executed before any of those methods.

Is there some way to say explicitly "I want this to be executed before any callback", or do I just have to subscribe myself as first subscriber to the `Observable` before `return`ing it from my utility method, and update the `AtomicBoolean` in that subscriber?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: the piece of code was a bit complex and not mine, so I didn't understand it well when asking the question.

Basically the code was like below; the observable emits 1 or 2 values.
The code relied on `onNext` callbacks of subscriber. Most of the time (surprisingly) it worked fine, i.e. `onNext` would see the value of the boolean as the original author wanted it to be, but sometimes the `onAfterTerminate` would executed only after all `onNext` callbacks.

```
     private Observable<...> getData() {
        return dataStore.getData()
              .doOnNext(...)
              .map(...)
              .doOnSubscribe(() -> myBoolean = true)
              .doAfterTerminate(() -> myBoolean = false)
              .map(...)
      }

    Subscription mySub = getData()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread(), true)
            .subscribe(onNextDoSomethingWithABoolean,
               onErrorDoSomethingWithABoolean);
```

The main fix was to add `onCompleted` callback to the subscription and work with the boolean there:

```
    Subscription mySub = getData()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread(), true)
            .subscribe(onNextDoSomethingWithABoolean,
              onErrorDoSomethingWithABoolean,
              onCompletedDoSomethingWithTheBoolean);
```

Apart from that I also:

- changed from `boolean` to `AtomicBoolean`
- changed `doAfterTerminate` to `doOnTerminate`

Anyway this piece of code can probably be rewritten to avoid the mutable state at all.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `doOnNext()` operator in the observer chain that you return to your subscribers.

```
AtomicBoolean firstCome = new AtomicBoolean( false );
...
Observable<SomeData> observerChain =
  emitSomeData()
    .doOnNext( ignored -> firstCome.set( true ) )
    .share();
return observerChain;
```

Edit: Use `share()` operator to allow more than one subscriber.

Comment: `publish()` returns a `ConnectableObservable` which property you lose and the chain will never be `connect()`-ed this way.

Comment: Actually, I misunderstood the issue I had, and basically instead of (only) working with my boolean in `onNext`, I had to add also an `onCompleted` callback - see below.